# Xcode oclint analyzer

Tags: xcode, static-analysis

I want to use [oclint](http://oclint.org) (an Objective-C static analyzer) for my projects but the official [documentation](http://oclint.org/docs/) does not clearly describe how to configure it.

How do I use it?

I have installed the `oclint` package then copied [the script for capturing projects configs](https://github.com/oclint/oclint-xcodebuild/blob/master/oclint-xcodebuild) into a project's folder. Running this script creates an empty file named `compile_commands.json` and it does not fill xcodebuild.log with any data.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why you want oclint and not the built-in static analyzer which is already conveniently configured for you to use?

Comment: oclint provides more rules, also it provides mechanism for continuous integration

Comment: is this still worth it with Xcode 7 and Xcode server? We can have continuous integration and I'm sure Xcode's analyzer got better since 2013 but since I'm not sure, I'd rather ask.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this script will add anything into `xcodebuild.log`. It reads from it. You may want to manually run `xcodebuild` and save the output into `xcodebuild.log` before running the script.

Check out the [documentation](http://docs.oclint.org/en/0.7/guide/xcodebuild.html).

Comment: The link provided is dead

Answer (score 1):

I have had luck with the manual route of copying the script into my project's folder then executing it on the command line.

Though this does not integrate oclint's functionality into XCode, it does provide feedback via stdout.

From this feedback I then update my code to align with oclint's recommendation and iteratively run oclint until my code complies with oclint's rules.